# 404 when calling my wcf service in javascript - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, query-string

I am trying to call my WCF service and I am using jQuery's AJAX. Unless I am mistaken the problem seems to be when I try to get that data back in JSON format. I am unsure if the URL is correct.

**This is my service.svc.cs. I want to call AddNewQuery**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="WebDataService.svc.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace BRADAPI
{
    [JSONPSupportBehavior]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class Service1 : System.Data.Services.DataService<BradOnlineEntities>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("AddNewQuery", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetQueryByID", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }

        protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
        {
            base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
            //Cache for a minute based on querystring            
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpCachePolicy c = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache;
            c.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
            c.SetExpires(HttpContext.Current.Timestamp.AddSeconds(60));
            c.VaryByHeaders["Accept"] = true;
            c.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Charset"] = true;
            c.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
            c.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
        }

        [WebGet]
        public IQueryable<tblContactQuery> GetQueryByID(Guid QueryID)
        {
            IQueryable<tblContactQuery> biglist = (from c in this.CurrentDataSource.tblContactQueries where c.QueryID.Equals(QueryID) select c);
            return biglist;
        }

        [WebGet]
        public IQueryable<tblContactQuery> AddNewQuery(string QueryText, string UserID)
        {
            // Make NULL to remove compile errors   
            Guid GUserID = Guid.Parse(UserID);
            Guid QueryID = Guid.NewGuid();

            tblContactQuery C = new tblContactQuery
            {
                QueryID = QueryID,
                UserID = GUserID,
                QueryText = QueryText,
            };
            try
            {
                this.CurrentDataSource.tblContactQueries.Add(C);
                this.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();
                return GetQueryByID(QueryID);

            }
            catch
            {
                return GetQueryByID(QueryID);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Calling service directly in the browser]

[image: Calling Service in my JS - I am getting 404]

**My JS code**

```
function sendQuery() {

        userId = $("#hdnUserId").val();
        contactId = $("#hdnContactId").val();
        txtQuery = $('#txtQuery').val();

        var successFlag;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: "UserID='" + userId + "'&" + "QueryText='" + txtQuery + "'&" + "ContactID='" + contactId + "'",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                successFlag = 1;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                successFlag == 0;
            }
        });

        if (successFlag == 1) {
            alert("Thank you, your query has been sent to a member of the Alf team");
            $("#dialog").css("display", "false");
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        }

        else if (successFlag == 0) {
            alert("Query not sent to the ALF team");
            $("#dialog").css("display", "false");
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        }
    }
```

My success and error block don't get hit because it's not hitting the service. So it's not success or failure.

Any tips for changing my URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL value parameters aren't delimited by `' '`. Use `encodeURIComponent(...)` to correctly escape the parameters.

Instead of

```
data: "UserID='" + userId + "'&" + "QueryText='" + txtQuery + "'&" + "ContactID='" + contactId + "'"
```

try

```
data: "UserID=" + userId + "&QueryText=" + encodeURIComponent(txtQuery) + "&ContactID=" + encodeURIComponent(contactId),
```

Additionally your URL seems to be wrong, according to one of your screenshots. In https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtFlv.png the url is `http://stating1......com/alfapi/Service.svc/AddNewQuery?format=json?QueryText`.

This indicates that your `url` variable already contains a query, i.e. `http://stating1......com/alfapi/Service.svc/AddNewQuery?format=json` (the `?format=json` part is a query within your url paramater which you should avoid when using `data` from `$.ajax(...)`.

Instead change it to

```
var url = 'http://stating1......com/alfapi/Service.svc/AddNewQuery';

....

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        // move format=json from your url variable to data: part
        data: "format=json&UserID=" + encodeURIComponent(userId) + "&QueryText=" + encodeURIComponent(txtQuery) + "&ContactID=" + encodeURIComponent(contactId),
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            successFlag = 1;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            successFlag == 0;
        }
    });
```

See ["JavaScript encodeURIComponent() Function"](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. My URL was wrong as you said I think I needed some fresh eyes.